# how to fire event at certain frequency with python

Tags: python, frequency

I would like to fire an event at a certain frequency, for example 44100hz.
I would expect the code below to execute "print" 44100 times per second, but it doesn't.

```
import time

frequency = 44100
desired_interval = 1 / frequency

events = 0

time_now = time.time()
time_end = time_now +1

while time_now < time_end:

    events += 1
    print(events)

    # some time has passed, sleep for desired interval less passed time
    if( desired_interval > ( time.time() - time_now ) ):
        time.sleep( desired_interval - ( time.time() - time_now ) )

    time_now = time.time()
```

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is that python (or the console you are printing to, or the OS as a whole) just can't keep up. Keep in mind that graphical output is one of the slowest operations on a computer. Other than that, the code is alright.

Answer (score 0):

This is closer, even if most probably (quite sure) the event "print" is not fired at a regular frequency.

```
import time

frequency = 44100
desired_interval = 1 / frequency

events = 0

time_now = time.time()
time_start = time_now
time_end = time_now +1

while time_now < time_end:

    events += 1
    print(events)

    if( desired_interval * events > ( time.time() - time_start ) ):
        # abs mitigate the fact that sometime the result is negative.
        time.sleep( abs( desired_interval * events - ( time.time() - time_start ) ) )


    time_now = time.time()
```

Answer (score 0):

To see why things take longer than you think we have to use a *profiler*.

Having saved your code as `timer.py`, I ran the following;

```
python3 -m cProfile -s tottime timer.py
```

The result was:

```
37621
37622
37623
37624
37625
37626
         188134 function calls in 1.000 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    37626    0.840    0.000    0.840    0.000 {built-in method time.sleep}
    37626    0.104    0.000    0.104    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        1    0.045    0.045    1.000    1.000 timer.py:1(<module>)
   112879    0.012    0.000    0.012    0.000 {built-in method time.time}
        1    0.000    0.000    1.000    1.000 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

So, on my machine it ran 37626 times per second.
Most of that time is spent running `time.sleep()`.

The thing is, when calculating the delay, you don't take into account the time your python code takes to run.
It also doesn't take into account that Python is running on top of an operating system that is also running other programs.

Let's simplify the program to this:

```
import time

frequency = 44100
desired_interval = 1 / frequency * 0.72
events = 0
time_now = time.time()
time_end = time_now + 1
while time_now < time_end:
    events += 1
    print(events)
    time.sleep(desired_interval)
    time_now = time.time()
```

On my system, this prints *approximately* 44100 times per second. As you can see, I had to reduce the time spent sleeping by circa 30% to take the overhead into account. And this is just a toy program.

Looking at the desired frequency, it looks like you want to do CD quality audio processing in real-time.
In all honesty, Python might not be the right choice for that.

What you should do is wrap the *real work* you want to do up in a function and run the profiler on that. The results of the profiling will tell you if you can do the required work in the desired time.

If you can't there are some options for speeding it up;

- Use `numpy`.
- Use `cython`.
- Use `pypy`.

Comment: Thanks. How you calculated 0.72?

Comment: I didn't calculate it. I did a trial-and-error using split-the-difference. (start at 1, too slow. Try 0.5, too fast.  Try 0.75, ...)